# ledger for ceiling joist

Tags: ledger

What size ledger do I need to hang joists in garage. I'm using 2x10x20'8 inch joist #1 or # 2 lumber. 12 inches on center. Do I need to double up on the ledger as well. I will be attaching ledger to top plate and studs in garage with lag bolts. The space above joists will be used for limited storage.

Comment: The needed size of a ledger depends entirely on the means of mounting the joists, which we don't know about. Ledgers are almost never doubled. There's no point to that. Since a ledger is fastened to a structural surface at close intervals it's not considered to have a span, per se. That's a crazy long span for a joist, though, even 2x10.

Answer (score 1):

Your design (2x10’s at 12” oc spanning 20’-8”) will support about 38 lbs. per square foot for #2s and about 55 lbs. per square foot for #1s, depending on the species. (I used Douglas Fir-Larch.)

I’m assuming the joists will fasten to the ledger with joist hangers...not sit on the ledger.  So, I’d recommend a single 2x10 ledger (not a double), but it depends on the joist hangers you use. (The nails furnished with Simpson joist hangers are short and stubby. That’s because they take all the load in shear...and none in withdrawal.) You only need a single ledger, because you can fasten into a series of studs and a continuous double top plate...no spanning large openings.

Therefore, each joist will need a joist hanger that supports about 400 lbs. for #2s and about 575 lbs. at each end. Likewise, you’ll need lag bolts that support about the same per foot. I’d use 1/2” x 4” lag bolt at about 12” oc. Best practices would call for the lags to be staggered along the ledger, but keep them a minimum of 2” from the edge of the ledger.

Please note that this does not account for any seismic loading. If you live in a seismic zone, you may want to re-think this design, because the lags do not comply with withdrawal requirements for seismic requirements.

Also, please note that the design loads are TOTAL LOADS. You’ll need to subtract the dead load (about 5 lbs. per square foot) from those design loads to give you an allowable live load. (Live loads are the things you’re storing.)

Comment: Would you recommend the new Structural Screws (Ledgerlok or Strong Tie) in the place of 4" x 1/2" lag bolts.  2x10 vertical wood studs 16: o.c. Southern California. New span 20' 1" Joist will fasten with joist hangers.

Comment: @Victor I like Simpson Strong-Tie. (No nails, no hammering...could split old wood.)

Answer (score 0):

Really you want 2x12 joists for that span IMHO. Typically the ledger is the same as the joists. You are hanging the joists, on hangers, on the ledger right? I will be stronger that way.

Comment: Yes, using joist hangers on the ledger. If I put a beam in middle of span would the 2x10 be sufficient. For wood beam an LVL or natural lumber. The length of wood beam is about 22 feet, 4X12 or 4X10

Comment: It all depends on the weight you intend to put up there. The beam makes it a lot better. Typically they use I beams and loly columns for that. 2 I beams and 3 loly's for that wide a span like in a basement. Look up cripple (stud) spacing requirements for headers too, for amount vs spans for 2x 10. You have leeway because it does not hold up whats above it (eg. roof 2nd floor) I can only give standard practice. You may need a Master carpenter or at least journeyman to answer that.